# How to make Azure Web Api project REST endpoints only available to Azure virtual network

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

I have a .NET Web Api project with several REST endpoints that I only want accessed by resources from within an Azure virtual network I have created. Resources such as Azure Functions and Azure Web Roles will access these endpoints only. In other words, I do not want the endpoints publicly available.

So, I configured the Web Api application with my virtual network but apparently I also need to add the Web Api application to an Application Service Environment (which are quite costly from what I have read). To quote the Azure [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet):

`VNET Integration gives your web app access to resources in your virtual network but does not grant private access to your web app from the virtual network.`

Do I indeed need to use an Application Service Environment and just deal with the costs or is there another way I can achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not want the endpoints publicly available.

Until now,  Azure web app only supports for using an internal load balancer with the app service environment feature. If you want to make your Web API can only be accessed internally. An app service environment is required.

If you don't want to move your Web API to app service environment and your Azure function and web role have fixed ip addresses, you could configure the IP whitelist using ipSecurity configuration in your web API. For more information of ipSecurity, link below is for your reference.

[IP and Domain Restrictions for Windows Azure Web Sites](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/ip-and-domain-restrictions-for-windows-azure-web-sites/?v=17.23h)